# percentage difference between values from 2 arrays

Tags: python-2.7, percentage

I have 2 arrays

```
a = [12.4. 14.8, 89.0, 13.0]
b = [900, 55.9, 893, 45]
```

I am looking for a way to get the percentage difference  values for the same indexes for a and b to make a new array c for the percentage difference. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try something like:

```
c[4];

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    c[i] = ((a[i] / b[i]) - 1) * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
c=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
   c.append = float(a[i] - b[i]) * 100 /a[i]
```

Comment: c.append(float(a[i] - b[i]) * 100 /a[i])

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers do not calculate percentage difference but rather percentage change. Percentage difference would be calculated with:

[image: foo+bar]

Python syntax:

```
c=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
   c.append( abs( a[ i ] - b[ i ] ) / ( ( a[ i ] + b[ i ] ) / 2 ) * 100 )
```

C syntax:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    c[ i ] = abs( a[ i ] - b[ i ] ) / ( ( a[ i ] + b[ i ] ) / 2 ) * 100;
}
```

Comment: Please note that due to an error in chart.googleapi.com formula is not properly shown, the plus sign is missing. V1V1 should have been V1+V2.